# French equivalent for “Might as well”?

Tags: expressions, traduction, choix-de-mot

I understand that autant + infinitive works when there’s another verb, like “Might as well eat” - “Autant manger”.

But how would it be translated as a single statement?

“You could get two of them for the price of one if you like.”
“Eh, might as well.”

“My house is on your way home. Do you wanna just pick me up then?”
“Might as well!”

Comment: I don't know but I'll use "pourquoi pas" in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

"**Pourquoi pas**",   "**autant faire ça**" et "**c'est une idée**" sont des traductions possibles ;

- “You could get two of them for the price of one if you like.” “Eh, might as well.”
  « *Vous pourriez en avoir deux pour le même prix. » oui, pourquoi pas./Oui, autant faire ça. »*
- “My house is on your way home. Do you wanna just pick me up then?” “Might as well!” 
  *« J'habite sur la route pour rentrer chez vous. Vous pourriez me prendre au passage alors. » « Oui, autant faire ça !/Oui, c'est une idée ! »*